# Adding price calculator to a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have made basic ski hire list app.  Im try to add prices to the 3 ski options now with an option to total the price.  I guess a bit like a shopping cart, but simple.

So it works to select the type of skis to hire, but I really need to add a function to give price and a total hire price.

The selections all work well, apart from adding the prices together.  I'm missing something really basic, I know it

```
## Basic app to list what skis a group would like to hire

    ## Author:
    ## Date created: 28 Apr 2021
    ## Date last changed:
    ## This program calculates the cost of a days skiing
    ## Input: sample.text, Output: none

import sys

# Create the main menu
def mainMenu():
    while True:
        print()
        print("""### Ski Hire Shop ###

        Select a number for the action you would like to do

        1. View Ski hire options
        2. Select Skis
        3. Remove item from hire list
        4. check if item is on the hire list
        5. How many items on the hire list
        6. Total price of hire list
        7. Clear the hire list
        8. Exit
        """)

        selection = input("Make your selection: ")

# This is the workability for the menu items, links to definitions
        if selection == "1":
            displayList()
        elif selection == "2":
            addItem()
        elif selection == "3":
            removeItem()
        elif selection == "4":
            checkItem()
        elif selection == "5":
            listLength()
        elif selection == "6":
            totalPrice()
        elif selection == "7":
            clearList()
        elif selection == "8":
            sys.exit()
        else:
            print("You did not make a valid selection.")
    
hire_list = ["Basic Skis", "Carve Skis", "Race Skis"]
hire_prices = [25, 35, 45]

# Displays all items on the hire list
def displayList():
    print()
    print("---Shopping List---")
    for i in hire_list:
        print ("* " + i)

# Adds items to the hire list
def addItem():
    item = input("Enter the item you wish to add to the hire list: ")
    hire_list.append(item)
    print(item + " has been added to the hire list.")

# Removes Skis from the hire list
def removeItem():
    item = input("Enter the item you wish to remove from the hire list: ")
    hire_list.remove(item)
    print(item + " has been removed from the hire list.")

# Checks if certain items are on the list
def checkItem():
    item = input("What item would you like to check?: ")
    if item in hire_list:
        print("Yes, " + item + " is on the hire list.")
    else:
        print("No,  " + item + " is not on the hire list.")

# Totals the amount of items are on the hire list
def listLength():
    print("The total cost of you hire.")

# Total price of the hie list
def totalPrice():
    
# Use this to clear the list
    def clearList():
        hire_list.clear()
        print("The shopping list is now empty.")

mainMenu()
```

Comment: Your code lacks logic to relate an item with its price. You can use dictionary for that. Also, what if a user adds something totally new item via addItem()

Comment: Thanks, so use a dictionary rather than the list for the items and prices.  This is the first full program Ive worked on :)

Comment: You might be interested in the libraries [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) and [click](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/) they are the major command line interface parsing libraries for python as far as I know. You could also try to use configuration files (e.g. json/yaml) such that you can define prices for specific items sparately from your calculator untangling the logic from the information. Later on you could swap that out with a small database like sqlite etc. Also see https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I could not understand what your problem is, could you please explain what is your problem? Aside of trying to implement this function? For example, if you don't know how to do it, or if you need help to achieve it.

Comment: Hi Esdeas.  My problem is I know that I want to add a pricing feature, but its how I can apply this or do I start again in a different way.  I know that I want to apply prices to the 'ski hire' options, and a total.  Simple math, but Im trying more to work out the format and where the logic needs to be to work in this process.